# Physical Meaning of Phase Ambiguity

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What is the physical significance of multiplying a quantum state $|A>$ by a phase factor $e^{i\theta}$. This does not have any effect on the normalization of the state so what is it physically? Does it have to do with the waves and their phase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's kind of an indirect meaning to it. Suppose you have a photon flying along. Photons seem to experience infinite time dilation and so there's no oscillating thing that the photon is "carrying with it" to have its particular frequency: rather that frequency comes via some sort of interaction with its surroundings. Phase factors are how that sort of wavey information enters the quantum theory. By itself, the photon/qubit/whatever cannot observe this phase factor; it has no meaning in the subsystem. But the moment you start to have two systems with a phase *difference* between them, you have interference effects with that phase.

With charged fields in addition the quantum phase becomes identified with the electromagnetic gauge symmetry, and actually leads to a conservation of electric charge term. So if you like, the physical meaning can also be "charge is a conserved quantity."

Answer (score 4):

There is no physical relevance of a phase in front of a phase vector, as this is unobservable, hence unphysical. In the geometric approach to quantum mechanics this can be viewed as a gauge freedom that can be used to reduce the total Hilbert space to the *quantum phase space*, i.e. the projective Hilbert space (equipped with a natural Kähler structure).